# DeprecationWarning: np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use a.item() instead 'a.item() instead', DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)

Tags: tensorflow, deprecation-warning

I've installed `tensorflow` as per these [installation instructions], but when I try to test my installation by running:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I received this warning:

---

> WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in
>   TensorFlow 2.0. For more information, please see:   *
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
>   * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
>
> C:\Users\765349\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py:546:
>   DeprecationWarning: np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16,
>   use a.item() instead   'a.item() instead', DeprecationWarning,
>   stacklevel=1) .W0227 17:59:32.231242 10540 deprecation.py:323] From
>   C:\Users\765349\Downloads\models\research\object_detection\anchor_generators\grid_anchor_generator.py:59:
>   to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.cast
>   instead.

---

Ran 22 tests in 0.141s

OK (skipped=1)

---

Please help me how to remove it and if I don't remove it will it cause any trouble when I start working with API.

Comment: This is a warning from numpy.  It says that "asscalar" is deprecated and you should use whatever they made to replace it.